# Angular service doesn't update the value of object

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing a simple service to set and get the value of an object. The code send's the value to the setter but the next time I'm getting the code, the values are still the same. Can you please look into the code and tell me what I'm missing? (I didn't include all the component header and imports to keep this short.)

```
//service.ts
export class NavService {

   private location;

   constructor(){

       this.location = {
          next:'',
          back: ''
       }
   }
   setLocation(back:string, next:string){
      this.location.next = next;
      this.location.back = back;
   }

   getLocation(){

     return this.location
   }

}
```

In my view, I have a button that calls the next() or back() to update the location.

```
export class PlanComponent {

   location;
   currentPage : string = 'start';


   constructor(private nav:NavService){}

  forward(){
     this.location = this.nav.getLocation();
     this.currentPage = this.location.next;

   }

 }
```

New location is loading a new component. The new component is suppose to set the new location. But in the parent component, when I try to get the location, I get the same old values.

```
 export class AboutComponent {

    constructor(private nav: NavService){
       this.nav.setLocation('start', 'about');
   }
 }
```

Really appreciate your time to go through this!

Comment: Not sure whether this is a typo, but it looks to me as if you were calling a method that does not exist. You call `this.nav.setLocation('start', 'about', 'family')`, but the method is only defined for two input parameters.

Comment: @alex, I was trying to simplify the code and there could by some cleaning left out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because of `NavService` life-cycle, your component might get new instance of the service on every component creation. Make sure the `NavService` is provided on top level component or module:

```
@NgModule({
    /* ... */
    providers: [
        NavService
    ]
    /* ... */
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: that could be the problem. I'm importing the service both on the top and child component and declaring them in each separately. What would be the right way of importing and declaring the service?

Comment: importing the service in each component is OK, but it sould be "provided" (with `providers: []` declaration) only once, probably in the Application Module.

Comment: That was it. Learning about the providers the hard way. Thanks!